# display day from date class

Tags: java, date, calendar, show

I use BlueJ and an exercise I got is to make a new date class that can do a couple of things

first off is to dispay the date that you fill in like this 5-8-2000, so with ints. I think I need to import the calender but i don't know how to correspond the numbers to the actual calender date.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
public class Date{
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;

public Date(int day, int month, int year){
   this.day = day;
   this.month = month;
   this.year = year;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for [`Calendar.set(int year, int month, int date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29) which you can use with something like (where January is 0),

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(year, month - 1, day); // <-- like so.
```

To output the date from the `Calendar` you could use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) like,

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(df.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) you can do it this way

```
LocalDate date = new LocalDate(new Date());
int day = date.getDayOfMonth();
int month = date.getMonthOfYear();
int year = date.getYear();
System.out.println(day+"-"+month+"-"+year);
```